# if photo has uploaded successfully

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, http

I would like to be able to upload a photo to my website and once it is completed for it to locate to a different view controller. And if there is an error for it to do xyz:

like:

```
if (!error) {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tocity&country" sender:self];
}
else
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

---

### How I upload my photo:

so the objective c code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL
                                                 URLWithString:@"http://******.co.uk/****/imageupload.php"]
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                    timeoutInterval:20.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"image/jpg"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
                       (unsigned long)[imageData length]]
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[self imageDataToSend]];
    
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    
    if( theConnection )
    {
        [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
    
    [theConnection release];
```

and the `imageupload.php`:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("image.jpg", "wb"); // write binary
 
fwrite($handle, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
 
fclose($handle);
 
print "Received image file.";
?>
```

---

I have also noticed that there is no loading gif at the top of the screen of the iphone like this, when uploading the image how come?:

[image]

---

## Edit:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://******.co.uk/****/imageupload.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

//where does the http code come in?

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

Comment: @rocky and then obviously I need to call it to not be visible once it has been **successfully** uploaded...

Comment: ideas on what? isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: How you would make it not visible once the photo has been successfully uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PHP

Always add check to make sure you are actually getting something,

You can make use of [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) Try it like this:

```
<?php 
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
    $folder = "uploads/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo '{"success":true, "msg": "succesful upload, we have an image!"}'; 
    } else { 
        echo '{"success":false, "msg": "upload received! but process failed"}'; 
    } 
}else{ 
    echo '{"success":false, "msg": "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded"}'; 
} 
?>
```

#### Objective C

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL
                    URLWithString:@"http://******.co.uk/****/imageupload.php"]
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                timeoutInterval:20.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
                   (unsigned long)[imageData length]]
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[self imageDataToSend]];
//Send the Request
NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request 
                                           returningResponse: nil error: nil];
//serialize to JSON                                          
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

//parsing JSON
bool success = [result[@"success"] boolValue];
if(success){
    NSLog(@"Success=%@",result[@"msg"]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Fail=%@"result[@"msg"]);
}
```

Comment: depends, you can do it with JSON if you want see my edit

Comment: @Maximilian what do you need help with?

Comment: How do you, using objective c. Look at the JSON from the php page? and then do x and y for success and failure respectively?

Comment: @Maximilian see my edit, i may have typos but I trust that you can fix it if any

Comment: Does the php need to be in a different place to the one in my question? I am getting a lot of errors?

Answer (score 1):

There are different problems with your code.

1. If you send a POST request, the server expects you to send a body encoded using multipart/form-data when uploading files (the standard way). For the kind of request you are making, it would be more appropriate to send a PUT request. However, PHP is not the best language to work with PUT requests. (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php )
2. To solve issues with malformed POST requests, and at the same time to get better support for errors etc, I'd suggest you to use more advanced libraries, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It has builtin methods for uploading files (using correctly encoded multipart/form-data bodies) and better error handling.
3. Using POST requests instead of PUT ones (in your code, you're basically doing a PUT request even if you declare it as POST) has the advantage of allowing you to pass more parameters (without using headers) and better support server-side.
4. When you use proper POST requests, you can just follow the traditional file upload code on the server side: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Thus said, the activity indicator does not appear automatically on iOS. You have to invocate it with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

And hide it calling the same method (with the `NO` argument) again.

PS: Not related, but... In your code I see no authentications for file uploads. This allows everyone with any tool (including a simple cURL command) to upload files to your server. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have tried and tried, using AFNetworking! But I find it very difficult to understand! which direction would you reccomend I go in? the PUT or the AFNetworking (Even though I don't understand its features seem too focused on JSON).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I didn't realise that it was possible to find out the url through the iphone app? I feel like I am such an easy target!!

Comment: also with option 4 That link is very useful. How would you then comunicate back with objective c?

Comment: "Security by obscurity" doesn't work. It's damn easy to find URLs, even without the app. Anyway, I suggest you to go with AFNetworking, especially if you're not an expert. It's really easy: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task @Maximilian

Comment: For the link I posted in point 4, just implement file upload using POST requests (use AFNetworking to make that easier).

Comment: How does one find the URLs easily? Is it not just pot luck that they stumble across one? I have never quite understood how you could find a random .php file in a random folder in a random url. When the internet is so huge!

Comment: 1. What do you mean with "where does the HTTP code come in"?
2. Just use sniffers. Like http://www.wireshark.org

Comment: the `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"image/jpg"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
                       (unsigned long)[imageData length]]
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[self imageDataToSend]];
    
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
`

Comment: That's what AFNetworking is for. Just pass it your file name in @"file://path/to/image.png"

Comment: but the file is from an image picker? not a destination.

Comment: should I create a temporary path?